Bucle dentro de mensaje para envío de mail con listado
Tengo este código el cual he modificado un poco: lo que hace es consultar en la BD y enviar un email a cada persona (todo dentro del bucle). Lo que deseo ahora y es lo que más o menos he estado intentando hacer es que solo envíe un solo mensaje a una sola persona con el listado (bucle) de la consulta. Uso MySQL.
<?php
$bd=mysql_connect("localhost","usuario","contrasena") or die ("No Puedo Conectarme A La Base de Datos");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_select_db("basededatos");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
$fechaActualN2=("2024-09-03");
$to2 = "********@hotmail.com";
$subject2 = 'Recordatorio Personal';
$mailservi2 = 'Recordatorio@*******';
$mensajecumple2 = '<html>'.
    '<head><title>Personal</title></head>'.
    '<body>
    <img src="http://pagina.com/logo/logo.png" width="206" height="103"><br>
    <h2>Recordatorio Personal</h2>'.
    '<hr>'.
    'El siguiente listado de personal: '.
    '<br><br>'. 
   $result2=mysql_query("SELECT nombre, preaviso, municipio, cargo, id_contrato FROM tabla WHERE preaviso !='' AND preaviso='$fechaActualN2'");
'<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Cargo</th>
<th>Municipio</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
foreach ($result2 as $resultado) :                                    
<tr>
<td>$resultado->nombre</td>    
<td>$resultado->cargo</td>     
<td>$resultado->municipio</td>              
</tr>
endforeach;                               
</tbody>
</table>'.
'<br>'.
    '<a href="https://pagina.com/calendario/calend.php">Ir a Calendario</a>'.
    '<br>'.
    '<hr>'.
    'Gracias.'.
    '<br><br><span style="font-size:8px">Gracias por usar este servicio</span></body></html>';
$headerscumple2 = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headerscumple2 .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headerscumple2 .= 'From:' .$mailservi2;
mail($to2,$subject2,$mensajecumple2,$headerscumple2);
?>


Además de darle un título descriptivo a la pregunta, recuerda siempre evitar agregar información sensible aquí (como correo electrónico). Cientos de bots scrapean el sitio diariamente.

mil disculpas.. es mi correo lo siento!! mil gracias por tus sugerencias las tendré muy en cuenta...

Solo tenes que concatenar correctamente el HTML que estas generando en la variable $mensajecumple2
Ejemplo:
<?php
$bd = mysql_connect("localhost", "usuario", "contrasena") or die("No Puedo Conectarme A La Base de Datos");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_select_db("basededatos");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
$fechaActualN2 = ("2024-09-03");
$to2 = "********@hotmail.com";
$subject2 = 'Recordatorio Personal';
$mailservi2 = 'Recordatorio@*******';
$mensajecumple2 = '<html>' .
    '<head><title>Personal</title></head>' .
    '<body>
    <img src="http://pagina.com/logo/logo.png" width="206" height="103"><br>
    <h2>Recordatorio Personal</h2>' .
    '<hr>' .
    'El siguiente listado de personal: ' .
    '<br><br>' .

    '<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Cargo</th>
<th>Municipio</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>'; // Cortamos la cadena

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT nombre, preaviso, municipio, cargo, id_contrato FROM tabla WHERE preaviso !='' AND preaviso='$fechaActualN2'");
while($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    // Agregamos mas info la cadena
    $mensajecumple2 .= '<tr>
    <td>' . $resultado['nombre'] . '</td>    
    <td>' . $resultado['cargo'] . '</td>     
    <td>' . $resultado['municipio'] . '</td>              
    </tr>';
}

// Continuamos agregando a la cadena
$mensajecumple2 .= '</tbody>
</table>' .
    '<br>' .
    '<a href="https://pagina.com/calendario/calend.php">Ir a Calendario</a>' .
    '<br>' .
    '<hr>' .
    'Gracias.' .
    '<br><br><span style="font-size:8px">Gracias por usar este servicio</span></body></html>';

$headerscumple2 = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headerscumple2 .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headerscumple2 .= 'From:' . $mailservi2;
mail($to2, $subject2, $mensajecumple2, $headerscumple2);


PD: Es replicar la acción que ya habías realizado con la variable $headerscumple2

Te recomiendo usar una estructura de tabla para eso, algo como: aplicado a tu código
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Cargo</th>
<th>Municipio</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php  foreach ($result2 as $resultado) : ?>                                    
<tr>
<td><?php echo $resultado->nombres; ?></td>    
<td><?php echo $resultado->Cargo; ?></td>     
<td><?php echo $resultado->Municipio; ?></td>              
</tr>
<?php  endforeach; ?>                                
</tbody>
</table>


Hola @Nicolas gracias por responder... el mensaje en si esta dentro de una variable llamada $mensajecumple2 trato de adicionar lo que me dices pero me muestra errores.. no se podria guardar en otra variable ese listado y agregarlo a la variable esta..

puede probar con var_dump(), para ver como vienen los datos, este caso el arreglo y en base a eso recorrerlo y traer los datos. te recomiendo partir por lo mas simple la tabla sin las variables y de ahí agregar lo otro, pero creo que en formato tabla será mas ordenado y fácil de visualizar el contenido.

Le puse una modificación al código de la pregunta aun así me envía el mensaje pero no me llega el listado de la consulta en el mismo... me llega el mensaje asi   Resource id #4

edite un detalle porque tenia un tema con la sintaxis, importante que para mi ejemplo utilizo el "foreach" en lugar de "while".
